# how to access dynamic property in nsobject implemention in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I want to create a class method that tells me the amount of time I am doing something from a start date. I am using the dynamic property because I'm using parse subclassing

My interface looks like this:

```
@interface Event : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
+ (NSInteger)daysInEvent;

@property (retain) NSDate *startDate;
```

My nsobject implementation looks like:

```
#import "Event.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
@implementation Event

@dynamic startDate;

+ (NSInteger)daysInEvent{
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    if (self.startDate) {
// I get the error on start date in the below line    
    return [[Utils sharedInstance] daysBetweenStartDate:self.startDate andEndDate:now];
    }else{
        return 1;
    }



   }


+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Event";
}
```

I get the error: Member reference type 'struct objec_class *' is a pointer. Maybe you meant to use '->'?

How do I reference the start date in the above function?

Comment: The same way you do every property: by saying `self.startDate`.

Comment: Why are you using @dynamic for startDate?

Comment: @rdelmar because I'm using parse framework subclass and it requires it.

Comment: Did you implement the parseClassName method in your Event.m file?

Comment: @rdelmar I added the complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.startDate` to access it.